# How to do .htaccess redirect and HTTP cache for static images in a no-cookie subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, caching, cookies, mod-expires, mod-headers

We want to do redirects for our site photos from `domain.com/images/` to a no-cookie `img.domain.com`.
Currently, we have `images` directory in public_html, URLs are:

```
http://domain.com/images/subfolder-1/title-of-the-image.jpg
http://domain.com/images/subfolder-2/title-of-the-image.jpeg
http://domain.com/images/subfolder-3/title-of-the-image.gif
http://domain.com/images/subfolder-4/title-of-the-image.png
```

In cPanel, `img.domain.com` has been set to `publi_html/images`

We tried to unset cookie and redirect via htaccss. Yet, it does not work.

In htaccess,

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

## Re-directing
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?images\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.img.domain.com/$1 [L,NE,R=301]

# Expire headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 29030400 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 29030400 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 29030400 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 29030400 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 29030400 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 29030400 seconds"
</IfModule>

# Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header unset Cookie
        Header unset Set-Cookie
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
        Header set Last-Modified "Mon, 24 Mar 2014 00:00:00 GMT"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

We wonder what to keep/add/change in the above .htaccess code, which is located inside `images` directory, or if there are better ways. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` in `/images/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?images\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.images.domain.com/$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Great! thanks! this rule did the redirect! @anubhava